# Javascript function print an object properties in a formatted style

Tags: javascript, object

I want to print a javascript object just like php `print_r`. I don't want to use `<pre>` tag since I'm not targeting only HTML, more am on console.

I have written the following function and expect it to work, but it only works with first level members and does not move to the nested objects. However, using:

typeof item == 'object'

operator, I wanted to see if the current looped item is "object" which always returns 'string'. While if I check the type of that certain property off the function, it returns 'object'. Here is the function which should check for two levels but does not.
(Tested in FireBug)

```
 function print_object (array)
    {
       var type = "";
       function parse_object (array)
       {
           var stack = ""; // escaping the undefined string appended to the beginning
           for(item in array)
           {
            if(typeof item != "undefined")
            {
            stack += ((item+"\n"));
            }
           }
           return stack;
       }
       var stack = ""; // escaping the undefined string appended to the beginning
       for(item in array)
       {
        if(typeof item != "undefined")
        {
        stack += ((item+"\n"));
        }
        type += (typeof item+"\n");
       }
       console.log(stack);
       console.log(type);
    }
```

My object is as follows:

```
var myObj = {
    "name" : "mostafa",
    "lastname" : "talebi",
    "contact" : {
                "email" : "myEmail",
                "mobile" : "myMobile",
                "weblog" : "myBlog"
                }   
}
```

And is executed:

```
print_object(myObj);
```

Comment: there is a print_r function for js http://phpjs.org/functions/print_r/

Comment: hacking the json2.js library is a good head-start.

Comment: if u want to see the content of object in console just do console.log(myObject)

Comment: have you tried "`console.log(myObject);`"?

Comment: I need to make my own style

Answer (score 0):

How about using JSON.stringify, you can specify a custom tag such as "\t"

```
var myObj = {
    "name" : "mostafa",
    "lastname" : "talebi",
    "contact" : {
                "email" : "myEmail",
                "mobile" : "myMobile",
                "weblog" : "myBlog"
                }   
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj, null, "\t"));
```

Comment: @Mostafa: For a quick fix: `Function.prototype.toJSON = Function.prototype.toString`. For total control, you'll need to write your own stringifier.